# Writing Dynamic JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for a way to write dynamic codes in Jquery.

Please take a look at these codes below and here is its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9o21j05/)

Everything works as expected, but Jquery codes repeats and kind of long! Is there any way to turn this Jquery to dymamic one.

Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part1">Part 1</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part2">Part 2</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part3">Part 3</div>
<div class="tab-parts">
<div id="part1">
This is part 1
</div>
<div id="part2">
This is part 2
</div>
<div id="part3">
This is part3
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(function () {
     $('#tab-part1').click((event) => {
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part2, .tab-parts #part3').hide();
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part1').show();
     });
     $('#tab-part2').click((event) => {
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part1, .tab-parts #part3').hide();
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part2').show();

     });
     $('#tab-part3').click((event) => {
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part1, .tab-parts #part2').hide();
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part3').show();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take, based on *not* changing your html structure.  This could be done better with a change to html structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldfqhm1k/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part1">Part 1</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part2">Part 2</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part3">Part 3</div>
<div class="tab-parts">
<div id="part1">
This is part 1
</div>
<div id="part2">
This is part 2
</div>
<div id="part3">
This is part 3
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 60px;
  float: left;
}

#part2, #part3 {
  display: none
}
.tab-parts {
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

**JS**

```
 $(function () {
     $('div[id^="tab-part"]').on('click',function(e){
        var part = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
        $('.tab-parts [id^="part"]').hide();
        $('.tab-parts #'+part).show();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

How does this look?

```js
     $(function () {
         $(".tabs").click(function(e) {
           var target = $(this).data("target");
           $("#" + target).show();
           $(".tab-parts").children().not("#" + target).hide();
         });
     });
```

```css
.tabs {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 60px;
  float: left;
}

#part2, #part3 {
  display: none
}
.tab-parts {
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs" data-target="part1">Part 1</div>
<div class="tabs" data-target="part2">Part 2</div>
<div class="tabs" data-target="part3">Part 3</div>
<div class="tab-parts">
<div id="part1">
This is part 1
</div>
<div id="part2">
This is part 2
</div>
<div id="part3">
This is part3
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kasperite and Crayon Violent so much!  Your JS are short and work well.  I want to vote for both, but how to do so?